# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php

Не получается передавать результат внутри класса.

Вот html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="previntiv">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Название договора</th>
                    <th>Действия</th>
                </tr>
                <?=$Query->Arrays()?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вот класс, в котором происходит передача результата из одной функции в другую через публичную переменную вне функций...

```
class SQL_Query extends DB_Connect {

    public $array = array();
    public $sql;

    function Query ($query) {
        $this->Connect();

        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$sql) {
            echo "Errore: ".mysql_error();
        }

        if (count($sql)) {
            $sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            $this->array = $sql_array;
        } else {
            $this->sql = $sql;
        }
    }

    function Arrays () {

        $sql_array = $this->array;

        do {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$sql_array['name']."</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='?preveiw=".$sql_array['id']." target='_blank'><img class='icon' src='img/view.png' title='Предварительный просмотр' /></a>
                    <a href='?edit=".$sql_array['id']."'><img class='icon' src='img/edit.png' title='Редактирование' /></a>
                    <a href='?delprev=".$sql_array['id']."'><img class='icon' src='img/delete.png' title='Удаление' /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
        } while ($sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql_array));
    }
}
```

А это метод пост, в котором я обращаюсь в выше указанный класс с запросом...

```
$query = new SQL_Query();
$query->Query("select * from previntiv");

if ($_POST['save_new']) {
    $name_preventiv = $_POST['name_preventiv'];
    $editor1 = $_POST['editor1'];

    $query->Query("insert into previntiv(name, text) value('$name_preventiv', '$editor1')");

    if (!$sql) {
        echo "Errore: ".mysql_error();
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?page=preview");
    }
}
```

В итоге ошибка:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку:
$this->array уже не MySQL result resource, а ассоциативный массив, если судить по этому участку:

```
 if (count($sql)) {
        $sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $this->array = $sql_array;
    } else {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }
```

Comment: тогда подскажите, как правильно сделать???

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал попытаться отладить код. Обычно php, вместе с ошибкой пишет, в каком файле возникла ошибка и на какой строке кода.
Переходите в нужный файл на нужную строку и смотрите, что за код в этой строке. Допустим ошибка в этом участке кода
 while ($sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql_array));
Вы видите функцию mysql_fetch_array. Зная, как работает цикл do while и то, что функция первым параметром принимает результат запроса(если не знаете идите на php.net) вы понимаете в чем ошибка.